# How to redirect user to other page when refreshers page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi i want to redirect user to other page when user hits refresh button on keyboard, using React `react-router-dom' v5`

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    };
  }, []);
  const alertUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = "";
  };
```

Comment: do you want to see the page one time and the redirect top another page or like what?

Comment: No , i want if user hits refresh button then redirect to other page.

Comment: you can create smth like page_view conunter and store it.... and when anywho jumps on the page then increase counter, therefore when you hit Reload button just check your counter and do redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do just a history.push ?

```
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    const redirect = () => {
        history.push("/destination");
      }
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", redirect);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", redirect);
    };
  }, []);
```